# delete message on sqlite. jailbreak iphone

Tags: ios, sqlite, sms, jailbreak

In my application, i want auto delete SMS messages.  for example, when i click a button to trigger a method to execute SQL in sqlite.

the SQL is like this:

```sql
drop trigger if exists delete_message;
delete from message;
delete from madrid_chat;
CREATE TRIGGER if not exists delete_message AFTER DELETE ON message WHEN NOT read(old.flags) 
BEGIN 
UPDATE msg_group SET unread_count = (SELECT unread_count FROM msg_group WHERE ROWID = old.group_id) - 1 WHERE ROWID = old.group_id; 
END
```

it can execute successfully（the file is in `/private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db`).  but in the SMS message application, the messages were deleted, and the chat group was not.

iphone is ios5.1.1, jailbroken. Does iOS have another way to save messages?

i download sms.db, and delete the `madrid_chat` and `message` tables' data.  then i upload to iphone.  but in SMS application, I always have old data. was the delete unsuccessful? NO, when i reboot the device, and reopen SMS application, the data are clear.

does the sms db have a cache?

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete sms on jailbreak iphone can't success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422272/delete-sms-on-jailbreak-iphone-cant-success)

Comment: yeah,that topic closed,i thought that post is failed.. so i repost a new topic.

Comment: have you tried forcing the **Messages** app to exit?  by double-pressing the home button, and deleting it from the running app list?  does this work to *clear out the cache*?  also, please take care to write your questions clearly, or people are going to keep closing them (like your last one).

Comment: yeah,i tried forcing the Messages quit in the running app list.when i reopen the app. all messages in the datatables.need reboot the device will clear data.so , any other hide place save the sms cache data?i hope i explain my problem clear,my english is poor,forgive me`