# Is there a way to programmatically delete an sms from iPhone inbox?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jailbreak

My iPhone is jailbroken and I don't have to submit the app to the App store. So any solution is ok. I just want to know if there was a way to programmatically delete an sms containing a particular string from iPhone inbox?

```
setuid(0);

sqlite3 *database;

NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db";

sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database);

NSString *deleteStatement = @"delete from message";

char *error;
sqlite3_exec(database, [deleteStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) ;

sqlite3_close(database);
```

This is my code. It's written in the main method. There is nothing else in my code.

Comment: To assure you: yes, there is.

Comment: @iHungry it is possible.I have seen a few python scripts to do that on an iphone.I want to do it through objective c.

Comment: @iOsBoy, its not valid, apple could reject this app while app reviewing process.

Comment: @iHungry : "I dont have to submit the app to the app store"

Comment: @iHungry Bothered to ***read the question?*** "My iphone is jailbroken and I dont have to submit the app to the app store."

Comment: @iOsBoy The SMS database is in `/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db`, you can use `libsqlite3` to query and alter it.

Comment: @H2CO3 I want to modify it through code

Comment: @iOsBoy Now google what `libsqlite3` is. I'm not an idiot, I understood what you want.

Comment: I know what libsqlite3 is.It cant modify sms.db table

Comment: @H2CO3 and I already know where the sms db is located.It cant modify sms.db table.If it was possible then why would I ask this question? And why are you being so offensive?

Comment: @iOsBoy why "can't it modify" the table? Tried with root permissions (after calling `setuid(0);` from your app)?

Comment: @H2CO3 your method does'nt work.The sms db is intact

Comment: @iosBoy I bet you forgot to set the "sticky" permission bit on your executable and it's not actually becoming root. (But hey, without some code, it's hard to tell what's wrong.)

Comment: @H2CO3 I added my code to my question details.Please tell me whats missing

Comment: You have to take care of the triggers also. There should be a delete_message trigger.

Comment: @FabianoFrancesconi how do I take care of the trigger? do i drop it? if so please tell me how?

Comment: I think you should drop the trigger, perform the deletion and recreate the trigger. I never worked on the SMS database myself.

Comment: @FabianoFrancesconi which triggers are you talking about? and how do i drop them through my objective-c code?

Comment: @iOsBoy drop trigger if exists delete_message;

Comment: @FabianoFrancesconi It works.I have heard that after deletion I have to recreate the trigger.How do i do that?

Comment: I guess something like: CREATE TRIGGER if not exists delete_message AFTER DELETE ON message WHEN NOT read(old.flags). Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434735/delete-message-on-sqlite-jailbreak-iphone

Comment: @FabianoFrancesconi write your answer in the answers so i can select it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take care of the triggers also.

You can drop it using something like:

```
drop trigger if exists delete_message;
```

and then you can proceed eliminating the messages. After that, you should recreate the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER if not exists delete_message AFTER DELETE ON message WHEN NOT read(old.flags)
```

Anyway, in general, you can take a look at this other question very similar to yours: [delete message on sqlite. jailbreak iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434735/delete-message-on-sqlite-jailbreak-iphone)

Comment: Your a legend dude :). See my new question and see if you can answer it